# Random data sampling with oracle sql, data generation

Tags: sql, oracle, sample, data-generation, population

i need to generate some sample data from a population. I want to do this with an SQL query on an Oracle 11g database.

Here is a simple working example with population size 4 and sample size 2:

```
with population as (
    select 1 as val from dual union all 
    select 2 from dual union all 
    select 3 from dual union all 
    select 4 from dual)

select val from (
    select val, dbms_random.value(0,10) AS RANDORDER 
    from  population 
    order by randorder) 
where rownum <= 2
```

(the oracle sample() funtion didn't work in connection with the WITH-clause for me)

But now I, I want to "upscale" or multiply my sample data. So that I can get something like 150 % sample data of the population data (population size 4 and sample size 6, e.g.)

Is there a good way to achieve this with an SQL query?

Comment: Bit of an unusual request - is it a one off that you could just use the same input twice? e.g. `With population 2 as (select * from population union all select * from population)` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends, if you want all rows from first initial set(s) and random additional rows from last one then use:

```
with params(size_, sample_) as (select 4, 6 from dual)
select val 
  from (
    select mod(level - 1, size_) + 1 val, sample_,
           case when level <= size_ * floor(sample_ / size_) then 0 
                else dbms_random.value() 
           end rand
      from params
      connect by level <= size_ * ceil(sample_ / size_)
      order by rand)
  where rownum <= sample_
```

But if you allow possibility of result like (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), where some values may not appear at all in output (here `4`) then use this:

```
with params(size_, sample_) as (select 4, 6 from dual)
select val 
  from (
    select mod(level - 1, size_) + 1 val, sample_, dbms_random.value() rand
      from params
      connect by level <= size_ * ceil(sample_ / size_)
      order by rand)
  where rownum <= sample_
```

How it works? We build set of (1, 2, 3, 4) as many times as it results from division `sample / size`. Then we assign random values. In first case I assign `0` to first set(s), so they will be in output for sure, and random values to last set. In second case randoms are assigned to all rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CONNECT BY`:

```
with population(val, RANDOMORDER) as (
    select level, dbms_random.value(0,10) AS RANDORDER 
    from dual
    connect by level <= 6
    ORDER BY RANDORDER
)
select val
FROM population
WHERE rownum <= 4;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c6ec7605e42b7ca2a3b48ff42ed9170)**